# Alpine 3.3, Python 2.7.11, urllib2 causing SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, ssl, alpine-linux

I have this small Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.3
RUN apk --update add python
CMD ["python", "-c", "import urllib2; response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.python.org')"]
```

Building it with `docker build -t alpine-py/01 .` and then running it with `docker run -it --rm alpine-py/01` creates the following output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)>
```

Yesterday I got bitten by the recent OpenSSL 1.0.2g release, which caused `py-cryptograpy` to not compile. Luckily the guys from `py-cryptography` released a new version on PyPI a couple of hours later. The issue was that a function in OpenSSL got a new signature.

Could this be related or am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to install ca-certificates to be able to validate signed certs by public CAs:

```
FROM alpine:3.3
RUN apk --no-cache add python ca-certificates
CMD ["python", "-c", "import urllib2; response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.python.org')"]
```

Comment: Thanks, this did actually save me.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to upgrade Alpine as libssl needs to be upgraded with a patch

```
FROM alpine:3.3
RUN apk -U upgrade && \
    apk -U add python ca-certificates && \
    update-ca-certificates
CMD ["python", "-c", "import urllib2; response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.python.org')"]
```

apk -U upgrade will upgrade these:

- libcrypto1.0 (1.0.2e-r0 -> 1.0.2g-r0)
- libssl1.0 (1.0.2e-r0 -> 1.0.2g-r0)

Comment: yes, thanks, the accepted answer already was the solution by telling me to add `ca-certificates`. Oh, I see, in my case the upgrade was not neccessary, but thanks for the hint, it might come in handy sometime.

Comment: But don't these upgrades get applied anyway? I think that when I was installing `python-dev` i could see that it was upgrading all used libraries as well.

Comment: for apk, upgrade will "Upgrade the currently installed packages". In later versions of alpine there is a patch for libssl and libcrypto that is required. When adding, i.e. apk add python-dev, it will pull in the maintainers requested dependencies for that package - which may not be the same.