# can't build python docker image

Tags: python, image, pandas, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker image of python using the following dockerfile:
I'm looking to have the smallest image so I use elyase/conda:2.7 image as a base:

```
 # Pull base image.
FROM elyase/conda:2.7
MAINTAINER me
RUN opkg-install --verbosity=4 curl python-dateutil python-botocore && \
    curl --no-verify-ssl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && \
    python get-pip.py && \
    pip install --upgrade --user awscli && \
    pip install boto3 chardet patool
```

After running the command:

```
docker build -t repository.test .
```

I get this error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 26.11 kB
Step 1/10 : FROM elyase/conda:2.7
 ---> 4abdba6a4c51
Step 2/10 : MAINTAINER me
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 54b7c51ab2b9
Step 3/10 : VOLUME /tmp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 491cf0da6c97
Step 4/10 : VOLUME /efs-script-import-tmp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1b3167c560e7
Step 5/10 : RUN opkg-install --verbosity=4 curl python-dateutil python-botocore &&     curl --no-verify-ssl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py &&     python get-pip.py &&     pip install --upgrade --user awscli &&     pip install boto3 chardet patool
 ---> Running in 009d37b86f48
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/x86_64/generic/packages/base/Packages.gz.
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/x86_64/generic/packages/packages/Packages.gz.
Collected errors:
 * opkg_download: Failed to download http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/x86_64/generic/packages/base/Packages.gz, wget returned 1.
 * opkg_download: Failed to download http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/x86_64/generic/packages/packages/Packages.gz, wget returned 1.
opkg_conf_parse_file: Loading conf file /etc/opkg.conf.
pkg_hash_load_feeds: 
pkg_hash_load_status_files: 
pkg_vec_insert_merge: Adding new pkg=terminfo version=5.9 arch=x86_64.
pkg_vec_insert_merge: Adding new pkg=libc version=0.9.33.2 arch=x86_64.
pkg_vec_insert_merge: Adding new pkg=bash version=4.3.30 arch=x86_64.
pkg_vec_insert_merge: Adding new pkg=bzip2 version=1.0.6 arch=x86_64.
pkg_vec_insert_merge: Adding new pkg=libgcc version=4.8-linaro arch=x86_64.
pkg_vec_insert_merge: Adding new pkg=libncurses version=5.9 arch=x86_64.
pkg_vec_insert_merge: Adding new pkg=zlib version=1.2.8 arch=x86_64.
pkg_vec_insert_merge: Adding new pkg=libbz2 version=1.0.6 arch=x86_64.
opkg_install_cmd: curl
opkg_install_cmd: python-dateutil
opkg_install_cmd: python-botocore
pkg_info_preinstall_check: Updating file owner list.
**Unknown package 'curl'.
Unknown package 'python-dateutil'.**
**Unknown package 'python-botocore'.**
opkg_configure_packages: Configuring unpacked packages.
opkg_configure_packages: Reordering packages before configuring them...
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: pkg terminfo.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: Descending on pkg libc.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: pkg libc.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: Descending on pkg libgcc.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: pkg libgcc.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: pkg libc already visited, skipping.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: pkg bash.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: Descending on pkg libc.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: pkg libc already visited, skipping.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: Descending on pkg libncurses.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: pkg libncurses.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: Descending on pkg libc.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: pkg libc already visited, skipping.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: Descending on pkg terminfo.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: pkg terminfo already visited, skipping.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: pkg bzip2.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: Descending on pkg libc.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: pkg libc already visited, skipping.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: Descending on pkg libbz2.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: pkg libbz2.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: Descending on pkg libc.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: pkg libc already visited, skipping.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: pkg libgcc already visited, skipping.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: pkg libncurses already visited, skipping.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: pkg zlib.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: Descending on pkg libc.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: pkg libc already visited, skipping.
opkg_recurse_pkgs_in_order: pkg libbz2 already visited, skipping.
write_status_files_if_changed: Nothing to be done.
hash_table: pkg-hash, 24576 bytes
    n_buckets=1024, n_elements=8, n_collisions=0
    max_bucket_len=0, n_used_buckets=8, ave_bucket_len=1.00
    n_hits=10, n_misses=14
hash_table: file-hash, 24576 bytes
    n_buckets=1024, n_elements=60, n_collisions=2
    max_bucket_len=1, n_used_buckets=58, ave_bucket_len=1.03
    n_hits=0, n_misses=60
hash_table: obs-file-hash, 1536 bytes
    n_buckets=64, n_elements=0, n_collisions=0
    max_bucket_len=0, n_used_buckets=0, ave_bucket_len=0.00
    n_hits=0, n_misses=0
Collected errors:
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package curl.
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package python-dateutil.**
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package python-botocore.
/bin/sh: curl: not found**
The command '/bin/sh -c opkg-install --verbosity=4 curl python-dateutil python-botocore &&     curl --no-verify-ssl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py &&     python get-pip.py &&     pip install --upgrade --user awscli &&     pip install boto3 chardet patool' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I can't figure out how to install there packages that are necessary for my application

Comment: Please add verbosity option to `opkg-install` (`--verbosity=4`) and `pip` (`--verbose`) to have more information why it failed.

Comment: As you are overwriting `/bin/python` with your pyrun2.7, maybe opkg-install and pip packages can't run on it?

Comment: I want to make a small image so I'm using Pyrun.

Comment: it says: it is not compatible with this Python
`(from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pandas/); it is not compatible with this Python` please check question update

Comment: Python is already in your base image, so changing it to another won't allow you to gain any space.

Comment: You mean busybox has already python installed? I don't think so

Comment: Correct it's not in your base image but it's installed as a dependence of python-pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are now using an old image [elyase/conda:2.7](https://hub.docker.com/r/elyase/conda/) which references http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/x86_64/generic/packages, but looks like it's now http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/x86/64/packages.

You need to fix this URL in `/etc/opkg.conf`

Here is a Dockerfile for a relatively small image (105M) that should almost do the job:

```
FROM alpine

# Runtime packages
RUN apk add --no-cache py-numpy sqlite-libs \
# Build packages
 && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
          py-pip \
          musl-dev g++ python-dev py-numpy-dev \
          ca-certificates \
# Runtime pip packages
 && pip install boto3 chardet patool \
# Pandas
 && pip install pandas \
# Cleaning
 && apk del .build-deps \
 && rm -rf /root/.cache/ /var/cache/misc/*
```

You can adapt it to install any other lib you need, or install numpy with pip, so you won't have python and you will be able just use `pyrun` like you did before.

Answer (score 0):

```
Unknown package 'awscli'.
Unknown package 'python-botocore'.
```

=> Pretty clear: 'awscli' and 'python-botocore' are not available openwrt packages, you should install them with pip I guess

```
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] unknown error (_ssl.c:661) -- Some packages may not be found!
```

=> [Alpine 3.3, Python 2.7.11, urllib2 causing SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762510/alpine-3-3-python-2-7-11-urllib2-causing-ssl-certificate-verify-failed): you need to install the opkg package `ca-certificates`.

But, then it will fails because it will try to build C-code so you have to install python headers and co.

Comment: How to install python headers?

Comment: I got   `Unknown package 'ca-certificates'`