# SSL Error certificate verification failed when using requests module on alpine linux but works fine on my windows machine

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I am using python requests module to make few API calls. i have to provide certificates to validate it. I have provided pem file to "cert" and ca to "verify" and it works fine on my windows machine.

When the same code is ran in an docker container it gives me

> certificate verification failed error.

OS - Alpine Linux.

any thoughts on this would be appriciated.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There are similar questions like [Alpine 3.3, Python 2.7.11, urllib2 causing SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762510/alpine-3-3-python-2-7-11-urllib2-causing-ssl-certificate-verify-failed). Neither you show how your problem differs from the ones described in other questions and whey the solutions offered there don't work. Nor do you provide enough information to make it possible to reproduce your problem.